# CSS - Linear gradient transparency on both side of image

Tags: css, transparency, linear-gradients

### tl;dr

Is there any way to add transparency to images in CSS with `-webkit-linear-gradient` on left, and right side of the image?

### Long Version

I have an image I want to add transparency - with pure CSS - on both side of it avoiding using any image editor like Photoshop, Gimp, etc. I have tried to use `-webkit-linear-gradient` but it uses rgba() function to define color stops.

So this snippet

```
height: 200px;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1));
```

does this:

[image]

In this example the last parameter in the rgba() defines the transparency of the color. So far so good. If I put `right` in the `-webkit-linear-gradient` the image above would show the opposite. *(You don't say?!)*

I want somehow to merge the two, and create a gradient that goes to transparent on both side. Only not with gradient. With an image.

I also tried to work around with `box-shadow` and `radial-gradient` but I couldn't figure it out.

**Is there any possible way to add transparency on left, and right side of an image using only CSS?**

### EDIT:

Example:
[image]

Comment: Not sure I'm quite getting it... do you just want three color stops?

Comment: Nope, I want an image fading on both sides into transparency.

Comment: Never mind, I get it. Side note, linear gradients are standardized and use a different syntax than the one you're using right now.

Comment: I added an example above. If not with `-webkit-linear-gradient`, then is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could use a wrapper div and then use color stops:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
div:before {
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 49%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)), color-stop(49%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 49%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 49%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 49%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 49%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/300" alt="" />
</div>
```

---

**Resources**

---

- [1 * Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Comment: My God man, who comments under the line of code? Jk, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Late answer but others can make use of it. You can put a gradient with transparency on both sides with just one line:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(255, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `mask-image` and `-webkit-mask-image` property, not `background`:

```
img
{
  mask-image: /*same as -webkit-mask-image*/
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0%, black 10%, black 90%, transparent 100%);
}
```

The above code puts color stops at 0, 10, 90, and 100 percent, leaving 10% of each side of any `img` tag semi-transparent. The `mask-image` property only uses the alpha channel, you can use any color you want for the non-transparent parts.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
}

.image::after {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, currentColor 5%, transparent 30%);
  }

.image::before {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, currentColor 5%, transparent 30%);
  }
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/800/400"/>
</div>
```

One way I've found to do this is to use pseudo classes and to stack them on top of each other. Make sure that the image container is relatively positioned and it should work for you (see example).

Answer (score -2):

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
}

.image::after {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, currentColor 5%, transparent 30%);
  }

.image::before {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, currentColor 5%, transparent 30%);
  }
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/800/400"/>
</div>
```